# How to give password validation in extJS in runtime

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

How to give password validation in extJS

I have a requirent in like image one and after entering the text image 2 should appear.  It should  give green to all the points which passed.

my Blank Image

[image: Blank Image]

After entering Text Image

[image: Entered Value Image]

Here is what I am trying but not getting what I want.

```
 regex: /^(?!.*(.)\1{3})((?=.*[\d])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^\w\d\s])|(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^\w\d\s])|(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[^\w\d\s]))[\x21-\x7E]{8,28}$/,
        regexText: ' Password should contain at least 6 character; Password should contain at least one number; Password should contain at least one lowercase and one uppercase letter
Password should contain at least one special character ',
        msgTarget: 'under'
```

Can anybody help me to achive that.

Comment: Which toolkit are you using? There are two ExtJs classic and modern, they are different.

Answer (score 1):

With 4 validation requirements, you're probably a lot better off having 4 separate validators, each of which evaluates part of the problem. So rather than doing a single regex that tries everything, do one validator that simply looks at the length, another that looks for a number, another that looks for a special character, and then a final validator that looks for the lowercase and uppercase letter.

Trying to make super complicated regexes is a huge time waster, and you wouldn't be able to indicate which rules were passing or not with just a single regex anyway.

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems. - Jamie Zawinski

Answer (score 0):

[image]
It is better to use simple validator functions to make a check. You can use the following code and change it to your needs (remove the error icon, change the style and add "Password strength: String" title):

```
Ext.define('PasswordField', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Text',
    alias: 'widget.passwordfield',

    //inputType: 'password',
    msgTarget: 'under',
    
    
    validators: [{
        errorMessage: "Password should contain at least 6 character;",
        fn: (value) => {
            return value.length >= 6
        }
    }, {
        errorMessage: "Password should contain at least one number;",
        fn: (value) => {
            return /\d/.test(value)
        }
    }, {
        errorMessage: "Password should contain at least one lowercase and one uppercase letter;",
        fn: (value) => {
            return /[a-z]/.test(value) && /[A-Z]/.test(value);
        }
    }, {
        errorMessage: "Password should contain at least one special character;",
        fn: (value) => {
            return /[~`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>\?]/g.test(value);
        }
    }],
    
    initComponent: function () {
        this.callParent();
    },
    
    onRender: function() {
        this.callParent();
        this.validate();
    },
    
    validator: function(val) {
        const errorMessages = [];
        this.validators.map( (validator, index) => {
            const icon = validator.fn(val) ? '<i class="fa fa-check-circle-o" style="color: green; width: 20px;"></i>': '<i style="width: 20px;">&nbsp;</i>';
            errorMessages.push(`<li>${icon}${validator.errorMessage}</li>`);
        });
        return errorMessages.join('');
    }
});

Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            title: "Sample Form Panel",
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            height: 400,
            bodyPadding: 5,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'passwordfield',
                name: 'password',
                msgTarget: 'under',
                labelAlign: 'top',
                fieldLabel: "Password"
            }]
        })
    }
});
```

P.S

Validation better to move to separate class.